# I am getting some error in most recent call last

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/app.py", line 24, in <module>
    wb.save('transactions2.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 397, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 292, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'transactions2.xlsx'
```

Comment: What is not clear about the error `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'transactions2.xlsx'`. You simply have no permission to open that file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Or may be that file is open!

Comment: Using `openpyxl`, a `PermissionError` is raised whether the file is open or is for example in Read-Only.

Answer (score 2):

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'transactions2.xlsx'
```

You most likely have this file `transactions2.xlsx` still open in Excel. Otherwise you have a process running, that still uses that file.

Comment: You sir! You... Excel at troubleshooting these issues

Comment: That would be an `IOError`, not a `PermissionError`, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, i just quickly checked it.
I created a new excel file, opened it with excel and then tried to open it inside a python script. The result was:

```[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.xlsx'
  File "E:\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    test = open("test.xlsx", "w")```

Comment: That doesn't say `PermissionError` or `IOError`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, i didn't copy the complete output. Silly me. Here it is:
`Exception has occurred: PermissionError
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.xlsx'
  File "E:\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    test = open("test.xlsx", "w")`